# Availability Group: ReadIntent connection failing

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups

I have two nodes configured in an AG group in a dev domain:

```
node1.DevDomain.com 
node2.DevDomain.com
```

My own workstation is on our production domain:

```
MyMachine.ProdDomain.com
```

When I test ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly connections from a machine within DevDomain I am correctly directed to the readable secondary. Note, the connection string specifies the Listener **name** as I am in the same domain.

However, when I test ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly connections from my own workstation (different domain) I get the connectivity error below. Note, in this case I need to specifiy the Listener **IP** since the I am outside the domain and the name will not resolve.

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is conf
igured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.).Exception.Message
```

Server: Windows 2012, SQL 2012. My machine: Windows 7.

I believe I've got the Routing Lists and URLs correct (and again, this works fine from within the domain).

I know the nodes of the cluster need to be in the same domain, but I would think I'd be able to connect from outside the domain by specifying the Listener by IP, but maybe not?

I thought perhaps I had a DNS issue in the DevDomain, but everything seems to resolve fine inside that domain.

Can I do this / what do I need to be looking at to resolve this?

Comment: Two things. Maybe instead of IP try with FQDN for your dev box. Did you check firewall setup for sql server and ag ports ?

Comment: FQDN won't work because there's no trust between domains so the name won't resolve. (Tried anyway and it failed.) There's no firewall issue as I can connect to each node individually by IP. The only issue is when going through the Listener with ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly.

Comment: Do you have listeners object in Linked Server on both nodes ? How it is configures ?

Comment: Btw for read only routing: Note that having your server configured to use dynamic ports is not recommended.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Linked Servers - they have nothing to do with AG groups. So, no I don't have any Linked Servers configured. Also, ports are static.

Comment: btw, are u able to particular node btw networks ?

Comment: @HenryLee have you ever solved this? I'm having the same exact issue

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember the final outcome of this was. Now I'm curious again. I wish I would have left a comment or answer...

Answer (score 1):

Script to create read only rounting:

/*

set up read-only intent routing

Test it:

```
sqlcmd -S "YOUR_LISTENER" -d dbname -Q "select @@servername" -Kreadonly 
sqlcmd -S "YOUR_LISTENER" -d dbname -Q "select @@servername"
```

*/

```
alter AVAILABILITY
group [AG] MODIFY REPLICA on N'node1.DevDomain.com \instance'
with (SECONDARY_ROLE(ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = all));-- not read_only

alter AVAILABILITY
group [AG] MODIFY REPLICA on N'node1.DevDomain.com\instance'
with (SECONDARY_ROLE(READ_ONLY_ROUTING_URL = N'tcp://node1.DevDomain.com:49598'));

alter AVAILABILITY
group [AG] MODIFY REPLICA on N'node2.DevDomain.com\instance'
with (SECONDARY_ROLE(ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = all));

alter AVAILABILITY
group [AG] MODIFY REPLICA on N'node2.DevDomain.com\instance'
with (SECONDARY_ROLE(READ_ONLY_ROUTING_URL = N'tcp://node2.DevDomain.com\instance:49877'));

alter AVAILABILITY
group [AG] MODIFY REPLICA on N'node1.DevDomain.com\instance'
with (
        PRIMARY_ROLE(READ_ONLY_ROUTING_LIST = (
                'node1.DevDomain.com\instance'
                ,'node2.DevDomain.com\instance'
                ))
        );

alter AVAILABILITY
group [AG] MODIFY REPLICA on N'node2.DevDomain.com\instanced'
with (
        PRIMARY_ROLE(READ_ONLY_ROUTING_LIST = (
                'node2.DevDomain.com\instancee'
                ,'node1.DevDomain.com\instance'
                ))
        );
go
```

Comment: Can you add how the script works ?

Comment: yes , just need free moment